# C Client library for Apache Cassandra

Tags: c, cassandra, client, driver, datastax-enterprise

Is there any C client for Apache Cassandra out there?
I have been looking for it desperately, but can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any C client for Cassandra. There is a [C++ library that supports the new CQL3 binary protocol](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver), but it doesn't look like it has C externs.